# Plotting a 3D surface and a plane in R

Tags: r, plot, 3d

I am trying to plot the plane determined by the equation y = x between 0 and 2 superimposed on a 3D surface described by z = 1/2 * x * y.

I "hacked" code from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18148332/4089351) to get a minimally satisfactory representation of the surface (wouldn't mind a fresh start on that), but I have no idea how to superimposed the 2D plane.

Here is the idea:

[image]

And this is what I got so far:

[image]

with the borrow code:

```
my_surface <- function(f, n=10, ...) { 
  ranges <- rgl:::.getRanges()
  x <- seq(ranges$xlim[1], ranges$xlim[2], length=n)
  y <- seq(ranges$ylim[1], ranges$ylim[2], length=n)
  z <- outer(x,y,f)
  surface3d(x, y, z, ...)
}
library(rgl)

f <- function(x, y) 1/2 * x * y
g <- function(x, y) x = y

x <- seq(0, 2, by=0.001)
y <- seq(0,2, by=0.001)
z <- 1/2 * x * y

plot3d(x, y, z, xlab="X", ylab="y", zlab="z", site=5, type = "n")

my_surface(f, alpha=.5, col="red")


my_second_surface <- function(f, n=10, ...) { 
  ranges <- rgl:::.getRanges()
  x <- seq(ranges$xlim[1], ranges$xlim[2], length=n)
  y <- seq(ranges$ylim[1], ranges$ylim[2], length=n)
  z <- outer(x,y,g)
  surface3d(x, y, z, ...)
}
my_second_surface(g, alpha=.5, col="blue")
```

Notice that the main problem (or difference with the sketch on the first graph) is that I can't make the greenish triangle appear. Instead, I get an oblique plane in blue.

Comment: So where is your code and data?